# cURL takes too long some times to perform a request

Tags: bash, http, curl

I have a simple yet powerful http server in house and I try to send many cURL requests with a random string generated in my side as data using a bash script. Normally server replies in very few ms but some random times the 'Time Spent' increases and it takes like 30' to continue.If I open another terminal and send requests it works fine. I'm pretty sure server is set up fine. Any ideas to debug-fix this? I see the output of the generated string and the cURL request on my screen.

Comment: Not a Stack Overflow question at first sight. But  http server logs would be  a good place to start with.

Comment: This is most likely to be a network or server issue, rather than curl itself being slow. Try using curl with `-v` or `--max-time N` (seconds) to see either where it is blocking, or force curl to exit after a set period to prevent hanging.